# git - how not to overwrite files that match?

Tags: git

I use a git for version control for my website.

I have my test and live sites set up as git repo, currently with a clean "git status" as I've just moved servers and fixed it all. I like to have them set up with git so I can see if over time they deviate from what is commit e.g. if I forget to upload a file.

I don't use git pull on my sites as it overwrites the CHMOD and CHOWN of my files (presumably to some default CHMOD) which can cause downtime.

I ftp changes to my test site and when they work I commit them (locally) and then ftp to live site.

"git status" will show these files as modified even if they match the latest version, I assume because it knows it is behind on commits and isn't comparing with latest version?

"git diff --cached" is blank

The only way I can get these files up to date is with "git checkout" which causes the CHMOD issues. "git pull" will cause merge conflicts.

Any way to get it to update to latest revision and ignore files that don't have any changes with the latest version? I never need to commit from these checkouts.

Comment: Git tracks the permissions of files in addition to their contents. Setting the permissions you want and committing will cause git to store it with those permissions.

If that isn't working, all I can suggest is maybe you're using a strange filesystem that doesn't support permissions properly?

Comment: I am using the standard file system on Centos 7. Git acts strangely with CHMOD, if I change the first part then it sees it as changed, but it commits it wrong, e.g. if I change a 700 file to 600 it will see the change, and I can commit it, but the change goes through as 664 (seems to be the default it likes). Git doesn't see i.e. in "git status" CHMOD changes to anything but the "user" part. I have also tried changing the config to "filemode = false" but that didn't help. If I pull a 640 chmod file it will change it to 664, but there will be no CHMOD changes in the diff.

Comment: I believe git is just setting the permissions at the default for new file creation by type. I think I can change the unmask setting. That won't help me in this case as I like to micro manage my permissions to be as secure as they can folder by folder. What I really want is git not to overwrite files when they are the same, rather than overwriting them and messing up the CHMOD.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are running a force pull git should not modify files that are the same.

```
git diff --cached
```

only shows modifications that are pending commit in the local repo, not pending changes in the remote repo. You can review what changes that are in the remote repo by running.

```
git fetch
git diff master origin/master
```

(assuming your current branch is named master)

You could try `git pull -Xours` but this might not work.

Unfortunately git does not save file permissions or owner information.
If you run the git pull command any files changed by it will be owned by the user running the command so you could try running git pull as the user the files need to belong to.

If you need to have specific permissions as well, or running git pull as the user does not grant the correct ownership for some reason, you will need to make a script that sets the correct permissions and ownership manually.
What you can do to make this easier is have that script set to automatically execute after you run a `git pull` by adding the script to `hooks/post-merge`. You can find more info about git hooks here: https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks.

There is also `git-cache-meta` which is a tool that apparently can save file permissions and ownership with git, but I don't know anything about using it.

Comment: git pull -Xours sadly didn't work. It's going to be a complex script to set file permissions as it's a large site with many types of files and varying permissions in sub folders etc. I was really hoping for a way to "hack" the git repo to think it was at the latest revision, so I could see if occasionally/over time there are any files which are not updated.

Comment: @user3616659 if you want to use it like that then running `git fetch` and then `git diff origin/master` should tell you which files are different and you could manually replace them.

Comment: Yes I think this is probably the best option, thank you.